# FadeOut a var with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fadeOut a variable, containing the classes I supplied:

```
var fadeOutDivs = "'.slider-bg , .inner-content , .about-app , .contact-us'"
$('.menu-li.a').click(function() {
    $(fadeOutDivs).fadeOut( 300 ).promise().done(function() {;
        $('.slider-bg.a , .about-app.a , .hand-with-mobile').fadeIn( 300 );
    });
});
```

Not working for me...

Comment: you don't need the inner quotes in fadeOutDivs

Comment: oh well, for some reason thought i already gave it a try, but i guess i didn't... thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seemed to be 'stringing' a string ;) You don't need the inner quotes when declaring your classes in the fadeOutDivs variable declaration.

You also have a random semi-colon after fadeOut callback function opening curly brace? but I am unsure if that is a typo when pasting into Stack Overflow.

Either way try this...

```
var fadeOutDivs = ".slider-bg , .inner-content , .about-app , .contact-us";
$('.menu-li.a').click(function() {
    $(fadeOutDivs).fadeOut( 300 ).promise().done(function() {
        $('.slider-bg.a , .about-app.a , .hand-with-mobile').fadeIn( 300 );
    });
});
```